How can we forward a failed std::expected up through the call stack
I have a std::expected use case like this:
class MyClass {
public:
    enum class error {
        e1 // ...
    };

    using index_return_type = std::expected<unsigned, error>;

    index_return_type add_data(data d);
    index_return_type update_data(data d);

    private:

    std::expected<void, error> expand_to_fit(data) {
        // Imagine i fail here
        return std::unexpected{error::e1};
    }
};

In add_data and update_data i would always immediately call expand_to_fit which can fail. If it does, essentially the error is already there, so i simply want to push it forward to outside. The best i have come up with is somehting like:
index_return_type add_data(data d) {
    if (auto it_fit = expand_to_fit(d); !it_fit) {
        return std::unexpected{it_fit.error()};
    }
    // The rest of the function
}

Live example.
But i don't love it.

The naming of it_fit is arbitrary, what if it could fit, but the expand_to_fit function failed for other reasons? It makes this code hard to read (and a little deceptive).
The ergonomics of this little check seem a bit rough to have to write all over the code and it makes the code harder to read imo.

Is there a better way to forward a failed std::expected up through your calling functions?
To extend this, imagine that i have a series of short checks. If i was using exceptions i might have something like:
void expand_to_fit(data) {

    if (!connected_to_database()) {
       throw std::runtime_error("Lost connection");
    }
    
    if (has_data(data)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Duplicate");
    }
    
    if (!is_input_in_max_range(data)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Cannot fit");
    }
   
    // ... Rest of function
}

How might we handle this with expected?

C++ just doesn't have that special dash of syntactic sugar that Rust has, to make this bitter pill go down easy.

You may be interested in p2561 by @Barry.

Feels like just throwing an exception instead of returning std::expected<T, R> would be better suited.

@pptaszni except that these are not exception situations, they are handleable and leave the system in a good state, so i thought i would try out expected

The idiomatic way would be to use one of the monadic operations:

and_then - returns the result of the given function on the expected value if it exists; otherwise, returns the expected itself.

transform - returns an expected containing the transformed expected value if it exists; otherwise, returns the expected itself

or_else - returns the expected itself if it contains an expected value; otherwise, returns the result of the given function on the unexpected value

transform_error - returns the expected itself if it contains an expected value; otherwise, returns an expected containing the transformed unexpected value


Since the expected type returned from expand_to_fit is void and the std::expected will contain the error if it occured inside expand_to_fit, you could use transform to return the expected unsigned if expand_to_fit does not contain error:
index_return_type add_data(data d) {
    return expand_to_fit(d).transform([&]{
        // the rest of the function wrapped inside a lambda
        return 0u; // return the expected unsigned
    });
}


hmm, this would make function flow in complex functions hard to follow. If we had say 3 checks in the function, we would end up indenting 3 times and moving deeper into lambdas right?

@FantasticMrFox It doesn't have to be hard to follow if the functions are broken down into smaller functions, which is usually a good idea anyway when functions are complex. It's not much different from having too many nested if/elses in a single function.

so if i have 3 pore condition checks one after the other (very common) and error returns say, something like is the database connected, do i have data, is the input in range, the suggested code for that is going to be if (auto e = connected().transform([&]{ return has_data(d).transform([&]{ return is_input_in_range(data); })}) : !e) { return e; } // Rest of function. This is incredibly unwieldy.

@FantasticMrFox No, it would be return connected().transform([&]{ ... };); /* nothing after here */ where the transforming lambda is only called if it's connected, otherwise the error returned in the expected from connected() will be propagated upwards.

@FantasticMrFox ... and with nested expecteds, it could look like this

Conceptually, when you have code such as
index_return_type add_data(data d) {
    if (auto it_fit = expand_to_fit(d); !it_fit) {
        return std::unexpected{it_fit.error()};
    }
    // The rest of the function
}

you are saying that you do not want to handle the unexpected case -- at least not here, but perhaps one call level up, though that's a decision to make for that function. The idiomatic way to deal with this is to use exceptions, where every function can determine whether it wants to deal with an unexpected situation or whether it wants to punt on it and hand it off to the calling location.
In other words, the way I read your question is that you want to shoehorn your use of std::expected into a situation where it is not natural, and where there are no natural solutions. Then just don't use that approach -- C++ is a multi-idiom language precisely because that allows choosing whatever approach is "natural" in a given situation, rather than forcing you to choose a specific approach in all situations.

Exceptions should be reserved for exceptional cases. Being out of memory is exceptional, while invalid user input is not. There surely are cases where you want to propagate the error up in a non-exceptional situation. Using exceptions for those cases just for the sake of error propagation is what I would consider unnatural. You may read the original paper proposing std::expected and a series of papers discussing why c++ exceptions are disliked by many, especially when being abused for nonexceptional situations.

@WeijunZhou I would disagree that "invalid user input is not" an exceptional situation as a general rule. If you have a function trying to parse a small piece of an XML file, several levels on the call stack down, but that file is just not XML-conformant, there is nothing you can do but jump back to the place where user code started calling the XML parser, several levels up the call stack. This very clearly calls for the use of exceptions. I would say that the same applies for the "Connection lost" example given in the original post.

I agree that the original post is an exceptional situation. I'm just having issues with your claim that the pattern if(...){return std::unexpected{foo.error()} per se is unnatural. OP should use exceptions for his case, but not for the reason you stated.

As the implementer of the API i get to decide what is exceptional and what is not. I have proposed a clearly contrived example. The use case that i have has many errors that can occur, none are exceptional, but all should be handled by the user. This is not an answer to the question of how to do this with expected. You are just saying dont use expected.
